# Continue using Laravel application while query is executing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query that updates all the table rows in MySQL database.

It can take up to several hours to finish and while the query is executing my application stay in loading state.

How can I continue using my application while the query is executing? I.e. run heavy queries in background.

Comment: Look into using queues. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues

Comment: You can queue the query, creating a job/command that execute the query in background. See more about queue here (change doc to your app version): https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using queues? They are built for this purpose.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues